# Chrome not applying style sheet css rules to certain elements with jquery hiding and showing divs (SCREEN SHOTS)

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, behavior

Hello I have a very weird problem in chrome I just cannot figure out!

I am creating an online text browser game, the problem I have you can check by navigating to here.

http://www.novactown.com/account?id=10003#_account

You will notice that you are on a tab called **Account**, below that is a black `h2` with the class `.playerBar` (it has the css `.playerBar {border: 1px solid #222;}`)

**Screen Shot**

http://www.images.novactown.com/eg1.png

Now if you click on the **Friends** tab, it will display the accounts' friends.

The accounts' friends are displayed **EXACTLY** the same as the `h2` on the tab **Account** but the css doesn't apply the `.playerBar` class even though each `h2` on that tab has the class `.playerBar`.

**Screen Shot**

http://www.images.novactown.com/eg2.png

Furthermore, if you navigate to the **Friends** tab and hit f5 it will now correctly display the `h2` and apply the `.playerBar` CSS.

The tabs are dynamic and are applied `onchange` binded to the `hash`.

I ran it through W3C validation and everything is clear.

Hope I made it clear enough, I just cannot think why chrome is doing this, I have checked in IE, Mox, Safari and Opera and everything is working fine!

Thanks

Comment: A screen shot would be quite helpful in this case.

Comment: I'm running Chrome and it's displaying properly, either you've fixed it or maybe it's a cache thing?  When you view source from the browser is your markup and css displaying what you would expect?

Comment: Hmmmm my chrome is up to date let me go clear my cache, shoulda thought of that really!

Comment: Ok totally my f***ing fault was my cache what a ridicolous mistake!! Sorry for wasting peoples time! Should I delete this question now or keep it up for other people to not make the same stupid mistake! Lol

Comment: Not ridiculous, I only thought of it because I've spent hours trying to get something to work only to figure out that it's my cache that hasn't been updating...

Comment: @cgwebprojects No no, don't delete this.  Caching is a common problem, and having this for people to reference will help.  Also, it will give Likwid_T some rep for answering correctly :P

Comment: @Xyan Ewing Thanks I didn't want to come out and say it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm running Chrome and it's displaying properly, either you've fixed it or maybe it's a cache thing? When you view source from the browser is your markup and css displaying what you would expect?